# Adding multiple If conditions in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code that Checks Col P for certain text , then check for Col M for numbers >1, if it matches then the number in Col M will be colored.

I just want to add one condition here:

-Additionally check Col O for the text "Fail", if it matches then check Col P for the string mentioned, then check Col M, if the number in COl M is > 3 , then color it in read (only if it has the string in Col P) or else do not color it.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim RemainingDay As Double '<--|

    With Worksheets("Latency") '<--| reference worksheet "Latency"
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row '<--| get row index of its column A last not empty cell
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For r = 2 To LastRow
            RemainingDay = 0 '<--|

            If Weekday(.Range("K" & r).value, vbSaturday) > 2 Then '<--| having 'Weekday()' function starting from "Saturday",
                Select Case True
                    Case InStr(.Range("P" & r).text, "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)") > 0, _
                         InStr(.Range("P" & r).text, "Moved to SA (Failure)") > 0, _
                         InStr(Range("P" & r).text, "Gold framing") > 0
                        If .Range("M" & r) - RemainingDay >= 1 Then
                            .Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                        Else
                            .Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
                        End If
                End Select
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the new `If` in 2 options:

**Option 1**: In an new line, before the `Select Case` (my preference).

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim RemainingDay As Double '<--|

    With Worksheets("Latency") '<--| reference worksheet "Latency"
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<--| get row index of its column A last not empty cell
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For r = 2 To LastRow
            RemainingDay = 0 '<--|

            If Weekday(.Range("K" & r).Value, vbSaturday) > 2 Then '<--| having 'Weekday()' function starting from "Saturday",
                If .Range("o" & r).Value Like "Fail" Then '<-- ****** add the If here ******
                    Select Case True
                        Case InStr(.Range("P" & r).Text, "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)") > 0, _
                             InStr(.Range("P" & r).Text, "Moved to SA (Failure)") > 0, _
                             InStr(Range("P" & r).Text, "Gold framing") > 0
                            If .Range("M" & r) - RemainingDay >= 1 Then
                                .Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                            Else
                                .Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
                            End If
                    End Select
                End If
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

**Option 2**: add it to an existing line with an `If` in it, using an `And`

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim RemainingDay As Double '<--|

    With Worksheets("Latency") '<--| reference worksheet "Latency"
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row '<--| get row index of its column A last not empty cell
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For r = 2 To LastRow
            RemainingDay = 0 '<--|

            ' ****** add the extra if at the line below with an And *****
            If Weekday(.Range("K" & r).Value, vbSaturday) > 2 And .Range("o" & r).Value Like "Fail" Then   '<--| having 'Weekday()' function starting from "Saturday",
                Select Case True
                    Case InStr(.Range("P" & r).Text, "Moved to SA (Compatibility Reduction)") > 0, _
                         InStr(.Range("P" & r).Text, "Moved to SA (Failure)") > 0, _
                         InStr(Range("P" & r).Text, "Gold framing") > 0
                        If .Range("M" & r) - RemainingDay >= 1 Then
                            .Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                        Else
                            .Range("M" & r).Cells.Font.ColorIndex = 0
                        End If
                End Select
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```